# Fit canvas to screen in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas

So I have this code base:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  const [ctx, setCtx] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCtx(canvas.current.getContext("2d"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ctx) return;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.current.width, canvas.current.height);
  }, [ctx]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        padding: 8,
        position: "relative",
      }}
    >
      <header>
        Some Header
      </header>
      <div style={{ margin: 40, flex: '1 1' }} ref={container}>
        <canvas ref={canvas} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's pretty basic example for a canvas element placed inside a container div.

What I want to do is to resize the canvas width and height according to the user's screen ( and make it responsive ).

So I found out two options:

To use `window.addEventListener('resize', ...)` or to use `ResizeObserver`.

I tried them both, but without any success, thats what I tried to do:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  const [ctx, setCtx] = useState(undefined);
  const [size, setSize] = useState([0, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resize = () => {
      const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = container.current;

      canvas.current.width = offsetWidth;
      canvas.current.height = offsetHeight;

      setSize([offsetWidth, offsetHeight]);
      setCtx(canvas.current.getContext('2d'));
    };

    resize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ctx) return;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
  }, [ctx, size]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        padding: 8,
        position: "relative",
      }}
    >
      <header>
        Some Header
      </header>
      <div style={{ margin: 40, flex: '1 1' }} ref={container}>
        <canvas ref={canvas} style={{ width: size[0], height: size[1] }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But from some reason it makes the height of the canvas greater in every resize cycle.

Whys that and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a problem using a package for the canvas you can use `react-konva` which will take care of the responsive nature really well.

So all you have to do is change the height and width as the window is resized and send them as attributes.

```
...
useEffect(() => {
 const checkSize = () => {
  setSize({
   width: window.innerWidth,
   height: window.innerHeight
  });
 };
 window.addEventListener("resize", checkSize);
 return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", checkSize);
}, []);

...

return (
 <Stage
  width={size.width}
  height={size.height}
 >
  ...
 </Stage>
)
...
```

Demo: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-responsive-stage-kpmy7?file=/src/index.js:365-650)

Comment: Is there a way to fix that problem without using external library? because then it means to change my whole code base ( I already implemented bigger code base than what I expose here )